# How to substitute into the general parametric equation?

Tags: systems-of-equations, substitution

I have know that the general form of a rotating function is as follows:

$$y(\cos\theta) - x(\sin\theta) = f\big(x(\cos\theta\big) + y\big(\sin\theta)\big).$$

Suppose that the following function will make a rotation by $45$ degrees:
$$f(x) = x^3$$

How can one deduce that the right hand-side substitution will be
$$
\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}} = \left(\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^3
$$

I know that
$$
\cos(45) = \sin(45) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Actually the question is how one can understand that $x^3$ should make $(x(\cos\theta) + y(\sin\theta))$ which is the right hand of the function to be $(x(\cos\theta) + y(\sin\theta))^3$ (i.e. cubed).

What if the function was:
$$
f(x) = \sin(a*x)
$$
or 
$$
\dfrac{y}{a}+\dfrac{x}{b} = c
$$
How can we substitute the given function in the general form as the first one?